# Does RSpec change $VERBOSE from true to false?

Tags: ruby, rspec, environment-variables, warnings, rspec3

I'm using Ruby 2.1.0p0, Rails 3.2.17, RSpec version 3.0.0.beta2.

If I do

```
export RUBYOPT="-w"
```

`bundle exec ruby dummy_code.rb` indicates that `$VERBOSE` is true, but `bundle exec rspec dummy_spec.rb` indicates that `$VERBOSE` is false.

I can make `$VERBOSE` true by running `rspec` with the `--warnings` option, but I assume that RSpec would not override what happens with warnings unless I explicitly ask it to do so.

Nothing that I can see in `spec/spec_helper.rb`, `config/environments/test.rb` or `.rspec` seems to configure warnings.

Does RSpec change `$VERBOSE` from true to false?

dummy_code.rb:

```
puts "*" * 50
puts $VERBOSE
puts "*" * 50
```

dummy_spec.rb

```
describe 'Stuff' do
  it 'does not do much' do
    puts "*" * 50
    puts $VERBOSE
    puts "*" * 50
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

RSpec (at least in version 3.2.0) only sets $VERBOSE when you using the `warnings` configuration option, but it's possible that you've got some code or preference file somewhere which sets `warnings=false`.

With a bit of detective work and Ruby's trace hooks, you can narrow down where to look. Ruby doesn't provide a trace hook for setting global variables, but you can approximate it by checking the value on every event:

```
set_trace_func proc do |event, file, line, id, binding, classname|
  raise RuntimeError, "Verbose was unset", "#{file}:#{line}" unless $VERBOSE
end
```

The stack trace will hopefully be enough to find it, or you could get a bit more clever with the contents of the trace function.